# Extra unwanted backslash in Morphia Query object

Tags: java, mongodb, character-encoding, morphia

I'm using [Morphia 1.5.2](https://morphia.dev/1.5.8/index.html) (Java 8) as a driver for MongoDB (V4.x), trying to use [Search for a phrase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-for-a-phrase), so my code looks like :

```
datastore.find(myEntity).disableValidation().search("\\\"" + textToFilter + "\\\"");
```

Debug looks good, but in running time the query is being sent with the three backslashes instead of just one, and the query return 0 results.

What am I missing? thanks!

actual generated query: `"$text" : { "$search" : "\\\"filteredText\\\"" }`

Comment: I tried to link to the answer in github issues.  I hope you found it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
datastore.find(myEntity).disableValidation().search("\"" + textToFilter + "\"");
```

Copied and pasted from the official github issue tracker at https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1453 .  I would have proposed this as an edit to a previous answer, as a reasonable person would have, but the moderators decided to delete the answer instead. Hope you weren't too delayed in getting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
datastore.find(myEntity).disableValidation().search("\"" + textToFilter + "\"");
```

Thanks @evanchooly !